# SSRS How to get the backgroun image of the 2nd of the subreport display on the main report

Tags: reporting-services

I am working SSRS report add watermark background image, I added the image on the report body background image of the subreport, and when run the report directly from this subreport the image displays all pages. but when running the report through the Main report which contains this subreport, the image only shows on the first page of the subreport. I have been googling and trying a few things but couldn't get it to work. I hope someone can shed some light on the situation for me.

Thank you in advance!!
MK.

I want to know how to get the report background to display all pages ( subreport background) when acess the report through the Main report.